# IServiceProvider::QueryService returned E_INVALIDARG in mfc

Tags: com, mfc, activex, activexobject

I am working on a small application. I want to embed the ActiveX Control and  want to remote it in a mfc application. For I need a `IServiceProvider` Interface of COM. `IServiceProvider` gives the access of `IWMPRemoteMediaAccess` interface. 
For that I am using this:

But It returnes `E_INVALIDARG` every time. Can anyone tell me what could be the problem.

```
IOleObject* oleObject;
CComPtr<IServiceProvider>   m_spProvider;
CComPtr<IWMPRemoteMediaServices> m_spServices;

HRESULT hr = CoCreateInstance(__uuidof(WindowsMediaPlayer), 0, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, IID_IOleObject, (void**)&oleObject);

hr = oleObject->QueryInterface(__uuidof(IServiceProvider), (void**)&m_spProvider);
if(SUCCEEDED(hr))
{
//Here It return E_INVALIDARG (hr = E_INVALID_ARG)
hr = m_spProvider->QueryService(__uuidof(IWMPRemoteMediaServices), IID_IServiceProvider,   (void**)&m_spServices);

}
```

I am not able to understand which argument is wrong. I more sure about first argument. can anyone tell me what it could be.

Thank You

Answer (score 1):

`IWMPRemoteMediaServices` is the interface you are supposed to implement on your side, not to query via `QueryService`. [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-RU/library/windows/desktop/dd564264%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

> #### Enabling Remote Embedding
>
> To enable remote embedding of the Windows Media Player control, **your program must implement the IServiceProvider and IWMPRemoteMediaServices interfaces**. IServiceProvider is a standard Component Object Model (COM) interface with a single method called QueryService. Windows Media Player calls this method to retrieve a pointer to an IWMPRemoteMediaServices interface.

Then WMP will call methods of this interface, methods that you implement. The code you are showing is an attempt to obtain WMP's `IServiceProvider` and services that the control implements. Vice versa, this is what WMP will do - it will discover services that you implement.

See [RemoteHost.h and RemoteHost.cpp here](https://github.com/Ylianst/Developer-Tools-for-UPnP-Technologies/tree/master/Samples/EmbeddedSamples/NewMicroAvServer/Win32_WmpML) on how your classes should look like.

Comment: Sry I just edited the query. There were one extra line code by mistaken. It is still giving error. Can you help me.

Comment: You are still trying (in your code snippet) to find this interface whereas you are expected to implement it and make it available and discoverable.

Comment: Roman R., I am facing problem to put the value of first argument of ` QueryService`. MSDN says it should be the `REFGUID (The unique identifier of the service)`. Can you tell what is this?

Comment: So I am telling you: you cannot fix it by replacing argument. You are to implement the interface on your side, then WMP will ask you for it.

Comment: Roman R., I am new to this topic. Can you give some links where I can know how to implement these interfaces. It'll help me.